# How do I know when it's time to distribute the load generation

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am making my JMeter test suites, which run nicely on my local machine. I need to understand when it's time to parallelise the load.

For example, I have a simple test suite that performs:

1. Login
2. Fetch recent messages of the user

In my reports, I see that the average response time increases proportionally if I increase the load.

For example, it may start from 0.5 seconds when I have 50 users and increase to 3.5 seconds when I have 200 users (average response times).

However, what is not clear to me:
Let's say I increase the load and add another 500 - 600 users, and the average response time will increase to some values of 10 - 20, for example. Is that an indicator of server slowness or the fact that my computer cannot produce enough load (e.g., limitations of bandwidth, CPU, or sockets)? What should I look at to clearly say, ok, I can produce X concurrent users load on this machine, and if I need more, I need to add more machines to the testing cloud (or go to the cloud)

Answer (score 1):

By default JMeter is not very suitable for running large-scale tests, it uses [1 GB of RAM maximum](https://sematext.com/glossary/jvm-heap/) and if you hit this limit JMeter either won't be able to conduct higher load due to excessive [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) or will crash.

Check out [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) for JMeter performance and tuning tips.

Once you ensure that JMeter is properly tuned you can monitor your operating system health in terms of CPU, RAM, network and disk IO using either built-in operating system tools or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/). Once any of monitored metrics start exceeding i.e. 90% of total available capacity it will mean that JMeter cannot conduct higher load as you machine doesn't have enough resources. In this case if the number of users is not sufficient you will need to switch to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) (not necessarily in the cloud, machines can be local as well)

Comment: Wow, that's kind of a surprise for me. Is there a reference to read about this 1GB limitation? I don't think I have seen anything like that.

Comment: If you cannot read the [reference post](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) in English maybe [windows batch file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.3/bin/jmeter.bat#L151) or [linux shell script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.3/bin/jmeter#L166) will be easier to understand

Comment: Aha, so as far as I understand it, it's more like a default setting that can easily be adjusted with these JVM flags